# looking for weather webpart for sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I'm after a simple weather webpart i can use in sharepoint 2013.
 Having found anything so far..
 Any links resources would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW.

I came across this site, but have not tested it out.

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Create-a-Snazzy-Looking-Weather-Web-Part-in-15-minutes-or-Less.aspx